# getComputedStyle returning auto in FF3.6, any workarounds?

Tags: javascript, dom

I need to do some alignment of columns in a page and so require sub-pixel widths. I'm using something along the lines of:

```
float_width = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(el, null).width)
```

So this works fine in recent FFs but always 'auto' in FF3.6. I would really like to make it work in FF3 too, since we're deploying RHEL6 systems and that comes with an old FF unfortunately.

So is the computing of the width done in a different way in older Geckos or is there a synatx issue? Is there any way of getting a sub-pixel width of a td in an old FF?

Comment: It's kind-of unfortunate that RHEL continues to ship with Firefox 3.6; it's not even supported by Mozilla anymore (since April of this year).

Comment: Agreed. Debian squeeze still has the same thing, drives me nuts. Also, IIRC the installed packages don't auto-update on either which is a very bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> float_width = parseFloat(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('width'));

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that's coming back with auto as well.